# How to create a concurrent thread group where a given concurrent users hit only once in given elapsed time?

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I need to make a concurrent thread group where the given number of concurrent users should hit only once, what happening now is that in a given period of time, it is hitting multiple times. See graph.
The concurrency thread graph is like this, what I want is 0-1 seconds, concurrent users are continuously hitting. I want concurrent users to hit once only. Graph should be like this.
[image]

I want a graph like this. All concurrent users should hit once and then, that's it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it using 
[Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) JMeter plugin:
[image]

Set number of rows, each with different Delay by seconds 0,60,120,.. so each will start every minute

Set startup and shutdown as 0 so you'll have peaks as desired

Comment: Thank you!
Just one more thing, I need to pass these start thread count as a variable that should be in arithmetic progression, i.e 2,5,8,11. How can I achieve that? 
Initial delay also, it needs to plus everytime. How can I do it dynamically?

Comment: @VirendraSharma Please ask a new question with what you want and tried in this specific case